# Allow outgoing connections for DNS

Tags: linux, security, debian, iptables, firewall

I'm new to IPtables, but I am trying to setup a secure server to host a website and allow SSH. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=/sbin/iptables

# Flush all rules
$i -F
$i -X

# Setup default filter policy
$i -P INPUT DROP
$i -P OUTPUT DROP
$i -P FORWARD DROP

# Respond to ping requests
$i -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT

# Force SYN checks
$i -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

# Drop all fragments
$i -A INPUT -f -j DROP

# Drop XMAS packets
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP

# Drop NULL packets
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP

# Stateful inspection
$i -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow established connections
$i -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
$i -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$i -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Open nginx
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

# Open SSH
$i -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

However I've locked down my outgoing connections and it means I can't resolve any DNS. How do I allow that? Also, any other feedback is appreciated.

James

Comment: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPDomainNameSystemDNS.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS connections are made to a remote host on port 53 using the UDP protocol with a fall back to TCP if the answer is too large for a UDP datagram.

You should allow outgoing connections with a destination port of UDP:53 or TCP:53.

Comment: How about this?: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/418c07c4d12f369d2131

Comment: @Jimmy:  Why don't you just suck it and see? Learn from your mistakes it's a really good thing.